# Place phone call from Cordova without prompt (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, url-scheme, phone-call

Is there a way to place a phone call in an iOS Cordova/Phonegap app without prompting the user like in fully native apps?

Placing a call with `tel://` and `telprompt://` show the same alert.

Comment: Ios by design always ask user to allow or not launch your call

Comment: @malcubierre I don't think that is always the case. In some instances, when a call is started with telprompt, (at least in iOS 7) it would not prompt the user.

Comment: You are right... it seems there is a native way, at least this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104883/making-a-call-programatically-from-iphone-app-and-returning-back-to-the-app-afte but it seems (searching plugreg) there is no currently any plugin that implements this code so you should create your own plugin.